# Why product image are not printing on New Order WooCommerce e-mail

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, printing

Each New order e-mail is sent on a printer via mail (epson connect) everything is printing fine except the product image. It's printing a cross instead.

I have tried with YAY mail customise but still it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to checkout your GeoFencing. Epsonconnect runs in Japan to grab your images, so if you do GeoFencing with your CDN, they get blocked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).